# Paypal Single Payout - Sender Insufficient funds error

Tags: python, paypal

I'm trying to do a Paypal Payout in the Live environment with a real bank account. The code already works in the development environment.

The problem is that Paypal is returning the following error:

```
INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS: Sender has insufficient funds
```

I'm using the `REST API` by calling

```
https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts?sync_mode=true [POST]
```

I'm using their python SDK and sending the `POST` message with this values:

```
{
    "sender_batch_header": {
    "email_subject": "Paypal Payout"
    },
    "items": [{
        "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
        "amount": {"value": "1", "currency": "USD"},
        "receiver": "test@gmail.com",
        "note": "123 Payout",
        "sender_item_id": 123456
    }]
})
```

I've contacted Paypal by phone and ask for the error, and they said that we need to MANUALLY put funds in the paypal account. My first question is: can I do this from their API? (I can't find out how)

They also said, that this problems is because I'am doing a `MASS PAYMENT` (with 1 payout item)... and they told me that I can avoid this problem by using their "`Regular Payment`" process. So my second question is what is the resource of their API that should I use? Or where is the information about their "`Regular Payment`" that I am not able to found on their WebPage.

Context: I already have the money in the bank account, and I want Paypal to automatically extract from there with every single payout.

Comment: It looks like the PayPal REST SDK has classes called `Payment` and `Payout`. That's probably what the PayPal rep meant. So, try using the `paypalrestsdk.Payment` class. Docs are on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK#create-payment) and the [PayPal REST API page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payments).

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna I can not specify a receiver with this Payment API. Here is the [Payment API definition](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that particular error message is because there is not enough funds in your PayPal account to cover the Mass Payment. For Mass Pay API to work, you must have the same amount of funds in your PayPal Balance that you are sending to recipients.

Here is some information on Mass Pay from the PayPal developer site:

> Merchants use the Mass Pay API to send money instantly to up to 250 recipients at once. To send payments to multiple recipients, merchants only need the recipient's PayPal account email address, the payment amount, and the currency code. Merchants can manually upload a file listing payments or create them programmatically using the Mass Pay API.

[Mass Pay Information from PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mass-pay/)

[Mass Payments Getting Started Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/MassPayOverview/)

For instance, if you are sending $2,000.00 to several recipients via Mass Pay API, you need to have $2,000.00 in your PayPal account to send to your recipients.

You cannot add money to your PayPal Account via API Call.

Here is how to add funds to your PayPal Account Manually:
[Adding Funds to your PayPal Account](https://www.paypal.com/selfhelp/help/article/FAQ1348)

You can setup Balance Manager to keep a certain amount of money in your PayPal balance. This would allow PayPal to automatically take the funds from your Bank Account to maintain a balance in your PayPal Account:
[Setting up Balance Manager](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/balance-manager)

Comment: I do not want to use MassPayments API. What I want is something that sends SINGLE payment/payout (one at a time) to my customers without needing to add credit to my paypal account. I want paypal to automatically retrieve the money from my bank account when I send a payment/payout. (They said that can be done with "Regular Payments") Now I'm trying to use [Adaptive Payments PAY](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) to see if I can pay without adding to the paypal account. You know something about this @pp_MSI_Jenn ?